# Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap when trying to sign with own CA

Tags: java, openssl, x509, keytool, ca

I am using a web application which is running in Apache Tomcat 6.0.44 uses oracle jre1.7u72.
I've followed the below steps to sign the server certificate using self created CA.[followed the steps from this link](https://metabrot.rocho.org/jan/selfsign.html)

creation of own CA

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt


openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

deleting the old certificate using keytool command

keytool -list -keystore <path of the keystore file> -alias aliasname -storepass password


importing the newly created server certificate signed by own CA 
keytool -importcert -keystore <path of the keystore> -alias alias -storepass password -file server.crt
```

and obtained the follow error 
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to x.x.x.x. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: can you please why it is showing this error and what is the mistake i have done here/in the website?

Comment: How did you obtain the secure connection? Show us some code. The error is pretty easy self explanatory.

Comment: Pasted the steps which i have done. Also i have shared the link. What is the code you are expecting out of this. Please tell what is the action to be taken care for this error.

Comment: Are you connecting with a web browser to the server (which has the certificate you've created installed)?

Comment: yes. self generated certificate using in the above step server.crt

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
An error occurred during a connection to x.x.x.x. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)
```

means that the server you've set up, and the browser you used to connect to the server do not have a common encryption algorithm.

You have do to either of those two things

1. Adapt your apache tomcat to support more algorithms (or more protocol versions). Read the [apache tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) and the [tomcat and ssl docu](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-ssl-howto.html) how to do that.
2. Adapt your browser. If you use (you did not state anything, therefore I'm using a common used browser) e.g., firefox check the support forum for an answer, if that does not work try [the solution from this blog](http://www.ryananddebi.com/2014/12/10/bypassing-the-ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap-error-in-firefox-34/). Basically you just need to change the `about:config` parameters and enable a few more cipher suites.

The goal is to have at least one common used algorithm on both ends - tomcat and browser. The algorithm used should be [secure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Weak_SSL/TLS_Ciphers,_Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection_%28OTG-CRYPST-001%29#Testing_for_Weak_SSL.2FTLS_Ciphers.2FProtocols.2FKeys_vulnerabilities) enough.